# superponer paneles

Tags: visual-studio

Estoy intentando superponer varios paneles en un formulario y que se alternen con la función click del botón que les corresponda. Uso este código, pero me funciona solo en un botón y en los demás me muestra todo en blanco como si no hubiese otros paneles. ¿Alguno me da una mano?

```
private void btn_maximizar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            btn_maximizar.Visible = false;
            btn_restaurar.Visible = true;
            this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
        }

        private void Btn_Inicio_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            PanelContenedor.Show();
            PanelVentas.Hide();
            PanelProductos.Hide();
        }
```

Comment: Buen día, podrías mostrarnos que es lo que te sucede? Cual es la función o procedimiento que no realiza la acción deseada?

Comment: Son paneles o formularios?

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! visual studio es una ide, y no tiene absolutamente nada que ver con tu problema... si es importante saber en que lenguaje estas trabajando....